# Strange behaviour when writing a string to a UTF-8 file (no BOM) - ANSI file being returned

Tags: c#, filesystems, .net-4.5

I'm attempting to write out C# string data to a UTF-8 file without a byte order mark (BOM), but am getting an ANSI file created.

```
using (StreamWriter objStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(SomePath, false, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
objStreamWriter.Write("Hello world - Encoding no BOM but actually returns ANSI");
objStreamWriter.Close();
}
```

According to the [documentation for the UTF8Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx) class constructor, setting the *encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier* parameter to false should inhibit the Byte Order Mark.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5 on my British (en-gb) computer.  Below is screenshot of the ScreenWriter object showing *UTF8Encoding* in place.

[image: The StreamWriter object]

So why am I getting an ANSI file (as checked with Notepad++) back from this operation?

Comment: the link shows the example as this UTF8Encoding utf8EmitBOM = new UTF8Encoding(true); not UTF8Encoding utf8EmitBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false);

Comment: Writing utf-8 encoded text to a file without using a BOM is without a doubt the dumbest possible thing you can do.  Whatever app is reading the file has no way to guess what the text format might be.  So of course has to assume the worst and that is ANSI.

Comment: Add `Ö` while writing your string and see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example string that you're writing to the file consists only of characters in the ASCII range. The ASCII range is shared by ASCII, UTF-8 and most (all?) ANSI code pages. So, given that there is no BOM, Notepad++ has no indication if UTF-8 or ANSI is meant, and apparently defaults to ANSI.

Comment: Since all the answers are broadly the same, I've accepted the first.  I tried the experiment again but with some Arabic text courtesy of Google Translate and I get the result I was after.

Comment: I've worked out that there is a trap for the unwary (like me) if you want utf-8 encoded files for a website and you edit them using Notepad++, Beyond Compare or other tools that guess the encoding from the content. They will save in the guessed format which may cause unexpected issues/behaviour at a later date when you try to introduce non-ascii characters.  What it means is that you have to keep an eye on the file encoding settings it the various tools that you are using and most particularly, just be aware there could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no BOM and no unicode characters, how do you expect Notepad++ to recognise it as UTF-8? UTF-8, ANSI and ASCII are all identical for the characters you are emitting?

(Even if you include some unicode characters Notepad++ may struggle to guess the correct encoding.)

Answer (score 0):

In "Hello world - Encoding no BOM but actually returns ANSI", no character is encoded differently in UTF8 and ANSI. Because of BOM absence, Notepad++ shows that the file is encoded in ANSI because there is no 'special character'. Try adding a "é, à, ê" character in your file and Notepad++ will show it as being encoded in UTF8 without BOM.